# Is JPA aware of triggers in database?

Tags: sql, jpa, eclipselink

I have a db with some field (version is the name of the field) as NOT NULL and there is a trigger BEFORE INSERT which sets the particular field, before inserting.

I am using Eclipselink as an implementation. When I try to persist the entity (so the version is null in the Entity), it throws an exception, saying version field can't be null.

Looks to me, that JPA are not aware of the database triggers.

Any work arounds?

Comment: Not a jpa or eclipselink user, but jpa shouldn't have to be 'aware' of the trigger - triggers happen within the database regardless of what is sending the SQL statements. Are you sure that the trigger is being executed? It sounds like the insert is being attempted without the null value being replaced. Try some testing with regular SQL from a query tool.

Comment: JPA is not aware of triggers in the database unless you've done something provider specific so that it knows to retrieve values after the insert.  Chances are though that the problem is JPA is inserting null for the value while your trigger only fires if the field is left out of the insert statement.  If that is the case, mark your field as insertable=false so that JPA excludes it from inserts.

Comment: Same problem. I ended up scrapping any trigger dependency with JPA. Seems JPA does not become aware of the non-JPA activities.